# How to remove scroll sidenav

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```html
<link href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="w3-sidenav w3-collapse w3-white w3-card-2 w3-animate-left" style="width:200px;">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="w3_close()" 
  class="w3-closenav w3-large w3-hide-large">Close &times;</a>
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 4</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 5</a>
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 4</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 5</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 4</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 5</a>
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 4</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 5</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 4</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 5</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 4</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 5</a>
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 4</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 5</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 4</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 5</a>
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 4</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 5</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 4</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 5</a>     
</nav>

<div class="w3-main" style="margin-left:200px">
<header class="w3-container w3-teal">
  <span class="w3-opennav w3-xlarge w3-hide-large" onclick="w3_open()">&#9776;</span>
  <h2>Responsive Sidenav</h2>
</header>

<div class="w3-container">
  <p>In this example, the side navigation will always be displayed on desktop computers and laptops (screens wider than 991px), and hidden on tablets and mobile phones (screens that are less than 991px wide).</p>
  <p>On tablets and mobile phones the side navigation is replaced with a menu icon that opens the navigation pane when clicked on: it will then overlay/sit on top of the page content.</p>
  <p><b>Resize the browser window to understand how it works.</b></p>
  <p>In this example, the side navigation will always be displayed on desktop computers and laptops (screens wider than 991px), and hidden on tablets and mobile phones (screens that are less than 991px wide).</p>
  <p>On tablets and mobile phones the side navigation is replaced with a menu icon that opens the navigation pane when clicked on: it will then overlay/sit on top of the page content.</p>
  <p><b>Resize the browser window to understand how it works.</b></p>
  <p>In this example, the side navigation will always be displayed on desktop computers and laptops (screens wider than 991px), and hidden on tablets and mobile phones (screens that are less than 991px wide).</p>
  <p>On tablets and mobile phones the side navigation is replaced with a menu icon that opens the navigation pane when clicked on: it will then overlay/sit on top of the page content.</p>
  <p><b>Resize the browser window to understand how it works.</b></p>
  <p>In this example, the side navigation will always be displayed on desktop computers and laptops (screens wider than 991px), and hidden on tablets and mobile phones (screens that are less than 991px wide).</p>
  <p>On tablets and mobile phones the side navigation is replaced with a menu icon that opens the navigation pane when clicked on: it will then overlay/sit on top of the page content.</p>
  <p><b>Resize the browser window to understand how it works.</b></p>
  <p>In this example, the side navigation will always be displayed on desktop computers and laptops (screens wider than 991px), and hidden on tablets and mobile phones (screens that are less than 991px wide).</p>
  <p>On tablets and mobile phones the side navigation is replaced with a menu icon that opens the navigation pane when clicked on: it will then overlay/sit on top of the page content.</p>
  <p><b>Resize the browser window to understand how it works.</b></p>
  <p>In this example, the side navigation will always be displayed on desktop computers and laptops (screens wider than 991px), and hidden on tablets and mobile phones (screens that are less than 991px wide).</p>
  <p>On tablets and mobile phones the side navigation is replaced with a menu icon that opens the navigation pane when clicked on: it will then overlay/sit on top of the page content.</p>
  <p><b>Resize the browser window to understand how it works.</b></p>
  <p>In this example, the side navigation will always be displayed on desktop computers and laptops (screens wider than 991px), and hidden on tablets and mobile phones (screens that are less than 991px wide).</p>
  <p>On tablets and mobile phones the side navigation is replaced with a menu icon that opens the navigation pane when clicked on: it will then overlay/sit on top of the page content.</p>
  <p><b>Resize the browser window to understand how it works.</b></p>
  <p>In this example, the side navigation will always be displayed on desktop computers and laptops (screens wider than 991px), and hidden on tablets and mobile phones (screens that are less than 991px wide).</p>
  <p>On tablets and mobile phones the side navigation is replaced with a menu icon that opens the navigation pane when clicked on: it will then overlay/sit on top of the page content.</p>
  <p><b>Resize the browser window to understand how it works.</b></p>
  <p>In this example, the side navigation will always be displayed on desktop computers and laptops (screens wider than 991px), and hidden on tablets and mobile phones (screens that are less than 991px wide).</p>
  <p>On tablets and mobile phones the side navigation is replaced with a menu icon that opens the navigation pane when clicked on: it will then overlay/sit on top of the page content.</p>
  <p><b>Resize the browser window to understand how it works.</b></p>
  <p>In this example, the side navigation will always be displayed on desktop computers and laptops (screens wider than 991px), and hidden on tablets and mobile phones (screens that are less than 991px wide).</p>
  <p>On tablets and mobile phones the side navigation is replaced with a menu icon that opens the navigation pane when clicked on: it will then overlay/sit on top of the page content.</p>
  <p><b>Resize the browser window to understand how it works.</b></p>
</div>

<footer class="w3-container w3-teal">
  <h5>Footer</h5>
  <p>Footer information goes here</p>
</footer>
     
</div>

<script>
function w3_open() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("w3-sidenav")[0].style.display = "block";
}
function w3_close() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("w3-sidenav")[0].style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

[image: How To Remove Scroll Sidenav]

How To Remove Scroll in Sidenav? i use w3.css and i want have sidenav like w3school. the scroll in sidenav was visible when my mouse not in the area. but when i drag my mouse in the sidenav, it show the scroll and i can scroll it down. i tried to do overflow: hidden, overflow: visible but its not work.
thank you.
http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_sidenav_hide&stacked=h

Comment: CODE? I can't see any code.. do you see? lol / use `overflow: hidden`

Comment: provide fiddle or snippet.

Comment: @pedram when i use that it make the scroll removed, but i cant scroll down

Comment: you need something to scroll, right? so it's a scroll, and you want to remove it, if appearance that scroll annoying you, you can use many plugin to make it pretty. like `nice scroll` or etc

Comment: @PitaJ still cant. please see http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_sidenav_hide&stacked=h

Answer (score 1):

You Need to Change in css as below.

```
.w3-sidenav {
      background-color: #ffffff;
      float: left;
      height: 100%;
      overflow: auto;
      position: relative !important;
      width: 30%;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    .w3-main {
      float: left;
      margin-left: 0 !important;
      width: 70%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that .w3-sidenav has `position: fixed!important;` you will have to remove that part first.

Answer (score 0):

Add "**overfow:hidden**" property to nav.

```html
<link href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="w3-sidenav w3-collapse w3-white w3-card-2 w3-animate-left" style="width:200px;overflow:hidden">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="w3_close()" 
  class="w3-closenav w3-large w3-hide-large">Close &times;</a>
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 4</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 5</a>
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 4</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 5</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 4</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 5</a>
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 4</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 5</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 4</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 5</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 4</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 5</a>
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 4</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 5</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 4</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 5</a>
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 4</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 5</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 4</a>  
  <a href="#">Link 5</a>     
</nav>

<div class="w3-main" style="margin-left:200px">
<header class="w3-container w3-teal">
  <span class="w3-opennav w3-xlarge w3-hide-large" onclick="w3_open()">&#9776;</span>
  <h2>Responsive Sidenav</h2>
</header>

<div class="w3-container">
  <p>In this example, the side navigation will always be displayed on desktop computers and laptops (screens wider than 991px), and hidden on tablets and mobile phones (screens that are less than 991px wide).</p>
  <p>On tablets and mobile phones the side navigation is replaced with a menu icon that opens the navigation pane when clicked on: it will then overlay/sit on top of the page content.</p>
  <p><b>Resize the browser window to understand how it works.</b></p>
  <p>In this example, the side navigation will always be displayed on desktop computers and laptops (screens wider than 991px), and hidden on tablets and mobile phones (screens that are less than 991px wide).</p>
  <p>On tablets and mobile phones the side navigation is replaced with a menu icon that opens the navigation pane when clicked on: it will then overlay/sit on top of the page content.</p>
  <p><b>Resize the browser window to understand how it works.</b></p>
  <p>In this example, the side navigation will always be displayed on desktop computers and laptops (screens wider than 991px), and hidden on tablets and mobile phones (screens that are less than 991px wide).</p>
  <p>On tablets and mobile phones the side navigation is replaced with a menu icon that opens the navigation pane when clicked on: it will then overlay/sit on top of the page content.</p>
  <p><b>Resize the browser window to understand how it works.</b></p>
  <p>In this example, the side navigation will always be displayed on desktop computers and laptops (screens wider than 991px), and hidden on tablets and mobile phones (screens that are less than 991px wide).</p>
  <p>On tablets and mobile phones the side navigation is replaced with a menu icon that opens the navigation pane when clicked on: it will then overlay/sit on top of the page content.</p>
  <p><b>Resize the browser window to understand how it works.</b></p>
  <p>In this example, the side navigation will always be displayed on desktop computers and laptops (screens wider than 991px), and hidden on tablets and mobile phones (screens that are less than 991px wide).</p>
  <p>On tablets and mobile phones the side navigation is replaced with a menu icon that opens the navigation pane when clicked on: it will then overlay/sit on top of the page content.</p>
  <p><b>Resize the browser window to understand how it works.</b></p>
  <p>In this example, the side navigation will always be displayed on desktop computers and laptops (screens wider than 991px), and hidden on tablets and mobile phones (screens that are less than 991px wide).</p>
  <p>On tablets and mobile phones the side navigation is replaced with a menu icon that opens the navigation pane when clicked on: it will then overlay/sit on top of the page content.</p>
  <p><b>Resize the browser window to understand how it works.</b></p>
  <p>In this example, the side navigation will always be displayed on desktop computers and laptops (screens wider than 991px), and hidden on tablets and mobile phones (screens that are less than 991px wide).</p>
  <p>On tablets and mobile phones the side navigation is replaced with a menu icon that opens the navigation pane when clicked on: it will then overlay/sit on top of the page content.</p>
  <p><b>Resize the browser window to understand how it works.</b></p>
  <p>In this example, the side navigation will always be displayed on desktop computers and laptops (screens wider than 991px), and hidden on tablets and mobile phones (screens that are less than 991px wide).</p>
  <p>On tablets and mobile phones the side navigation is replaced with a menu icon that opens the navigation pane when clicked on: it will then overlay/sit on top of the page content.</p>
  <p><b>Resize the browser window to understand how it works.</b></p>
  <p>In this example, the side navigation will always be displayed on desktop computers and laptops (screens wider than 991px), and hidden on tablets and mobile phones (screens that are less than 991px wide).</p>
  <p>On tablets and mobile phones the side navigation is replaced with a menu icon that opens the navigation pane when clicked on: it will then overlay/sit on top of the page content.</p>
  <p><b>Resize the browser window to understand how it works.</b></p>
  <p>In this example, the side navigation will always be displayed on desktop computers and laptops (screens wider than 991px), and hidden on tablets and mobile phones (screens that are less than 991px wide).</p>
  <p>On tablets and mobile phones the side navigation is replaced with a menu icon that opens the navigation pane when clicked on: it will then overlay/sit on top of the page content.</p>
  <p><b>Resize the browser window to understand how it works.</b></p>
</div>

<footer class="w3-container w3-teal">
  <h5>Footer</h5>
  <p>Footer information goes here</p>
</footer>
     
</div>

<script>
function w3_open() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("w3-sidenav")[0].style.display = "block";
}
function w3_close() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("w3-sidenav")[0].style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```